# Validate Windows Identity Token

Tags: c#, token, windows-authentication, identity

I am trying develop a simple web service to authenticate users of a desktop application using the windows identity framework, at present I am passing the token generated by `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token` via a post variable (it is encrypted and ssl'd,  Windows authentication is not an option given the layout of our domain's and the configuration of the server). I am passing the token back fine and converting it back to an `IntPtr`.

I am at a lost as to how to validate the token to ensure that it was generated by a particular Active Directory (or any for that matter). I have tried to create a new `WindowsIdentity` instance given the token however that just results in an Exception (message: Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated).

If anyone can provide any help or even hints I would greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to just use the token and leave the validation to Windows when you use the token to access a resource?

Comment: In my case I'm using a custom socket client/server solution where I want to authenticate users using windows authentication. Hence I need to transport a token or similar to the server for authentication, but I do not understand how. MSDN isn't very helpful.

Comment: Are the client and server on the same domain? Does the client authenticate to the domain when logging into windows?

Comment: I assume that you are looking for an Active Federation solution, some info about that can be found in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx

Comment: @MikeHixson: You are free to give an answer when they are.

Comment: @FrodeNilsen: Yes, but without WCF

Comment: [try this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29853/User-Login-For-WinForm-Applications)

Comment: If I understand what you want, this question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15251906/2164198 - the answer is to use WInAPI DuplicateTokenEx to duplicate your token and serialize it. Then you can use it for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

If I understand correctly your question, I know it's possible to do it doing direct API Calls. The LogonUser in the advapi32.dll is the answer. The following snippet worked for me

```
public class ActiveDirectoryHelper
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(
        string lpszUsername,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        out IntPtr phToken
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    public static bool Authenticate(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        IntPtr token;
        LogonUser(userName, domain, password, 2, 0, out token);

        bool isAuthenticated = token != IntPtr.Zero;

        CloseHandle(token);

        return isAuthenticated;
    }

    public static IntPtr GetAuthenticationHandle(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        IntPtr token;
        LogonUser(userName, domain, password, 2, 0, out token);
        return token;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool DoesUserExist(string userName)
{
    using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN"))
    {
        using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
        {
            return foundUser != null;
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve checking for if a user exists. This comes from the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and assembly.

Just pass in your username which you can get from `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` and this will return a true/false if a user if in your usergroup. (replace DOMAIN with your needed group name.)